# Возврат именованных аргументов из функции

Tags: python, функции

Итак, есть функция, принимающая различные свойства в таком виде:

```
obj.foo(text="one more string", url="127.0.0.1")
```

И так далее. Насколько я понимаю это просто **args - т.е. прием аргумента-словаря. Как мне вернуть из другой функции результат для этой функции? Как я сделал я:

```
def MyFunc():
   return {text:"my text", url:"any url"}


obj.foo(myFunc())
```

На что получаю много ошибок. Пробовал передавать функцию с упаковкой (*) перед ней, пробовал брать названия аргументов в кавычки внутри фигурный скобок.

```
# создание объекта
btn = BtnUrl(text="Goto", url="goo.gl")

# его класс
class BtnUrl:
   def __init__(self, **args):
      self.text = args['text']
      self.url = args['url']

   def Cook(self):
      return {'text':self.text, 'url':self.url} 

# сама передача в виде аргумента
 types.InlineKeyboardButton(**btn.Cook())
```

Это весь проблемный код

Comment: `obj.foo(**myFunc())` ?

Comment: 2018-11-21 20:52:53,749 (util.py:65 WorkerThread1) ERROR - TeleBot: "TypeError occurred, args=("'text' is an invalid keyword argument for this function",)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 59, in run

Comment: Похоже у этой функции нет аргумента с именем `text`...

Comment: Попробуйте привести воспроизводимые примеры функций

Comment: Но такое имя есть, прикрепил скриншот. types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = "ffffff") - вполне рабочий пример

Comment: Так вы можете привести в вопросе минимальный код, позволяющий воспроизвести проблему?

Comment: под вопросом есть кнопка править - воспользуйтесь пожалуйста ей, чтобы отредактировать сам вопрос ;)

Comment: Исправил, в разметке разобрался)

Comment: ваш код не рабочий... Класс `BtnUrl` не объявлен

Comment: Дело в том, что у меня несколько файлов сходного кода, но вся проблема где-то в этих строках. Добавил весь класс Btn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понимаю, вопрос сводится к передаче словаря переменных, заданных в одной функции, в качестве аргумента для другой? В таком случае, вам нужно разобраться с областью видимости переменных. И `locals()` в этом поможет:

```
def afunc():
    text="my text"
    url="any url"
    d={'1':1, '2':2}
    return(locals())

def bfunc(outerfunc):
    for key, value in outerfunc.items():
        print("{} : {}". format(key, value))

bfunc(afunc())
```

Получаем:

```
text : my text
url : any url
d : {'1': 1, '2': 2}
```

**UPDATE**

```
class BtnUrl:
    def __init__(self, **args):
        self.text = args['text']
        self.url = args['url']

    def Cook(self):
        myargs= {'text':self.text, 'url':self.url}
        return locals()

btn = BtnUrl(text="Goto", url="goo.gl")

def somefunc(outer):
    params=outer.Cook()
    for key, value in params.items():
        print("{} : {}". format(key, value))

somefunc(btn)
```

На выходе:

```
self : <__main__.BtnUrl object at 0x0ACEB090>
myargs : {'text': 'Goto', 'url': 'goo.gl'}
```

Либо передавать чуть по-другому:

```
def somefunc(outer):
    for key, value in outer.items():
        print("{} : {}". format(key, value))

somefunc(btn.Cook())
```

Результат тот же:

```
self : <__main__.BtnUrl object at 0x00D35870>
myargs : {'text': 'Goto', 'url': 'goo.gl'}
```

Comment: К сожалению, проблема не ушла, но спасибо, не знал об этом.

Comment: @Juriy359 Я обновил код для класса. У меня проблемы с передачей параметров нет. Я неверно понимаю проблему?

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснения, в моем коде многие ошибки тяжело отлавливать из-за работы с внешней библиотекой, но по данному вопросу я все понял.